# How to change header ("Contents") of automatic TOC when using Pandoc?

Tags: pdf, markdown, pandoc

When converting markdown to pdf with [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) (**version 1.12.1**) the `ToC` option adds an english header: "**Contents**".

Since my document is in Dutch, I would like to be able to put the Dutch equivalent of contents there. But unfortunately I couldn't find any configuration options for this, neither did I found clues in the `default.latex` file.

My query:

```
pandoc -S --toc essay.md --biblio "MCM Essay.bib" --csl apa.csl -o mcm.pdf
```

- I'm using windows
- I use MIKTex, like in the pandoc instructions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string "Contents" is not supplied by pandoc, but by latex (which pandoc calls to create the PDF).

Try adding

```
-Vlang=dutch
```

to your command line.  This will be passed to latex in the documentclass options, and LaTeX will provide the right string.

Comment: Wow that was easier than expected, that did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
-V toc-title="My Custom TOC Header"
```

to the `pandoc` command line will also work. See https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-set-automatically.